# R & propensity matching

Tags: r

I am new to R & propensity matching.  I doing a quasi-experimental study in which a group of 320 students received treatment and a group of 280 students did not receive treatment.

I would like to match individual students in the two groups based on gender, race and SES (these are nominal data).  Can I use R to do this?  Can someone send me a script?

Thank you, 
NJ

Comment: I don't think this should be on hold.  While it does specifically address R, there is an element of statistics here in that the OP asks.

Answer (score 2):

That is called exact matching, not propensity score matching.  You can use R to do exact matching.  If you want to do propensity score matching, I suggest you take a look at the packages mentioned on Elizabeth Stuart's website for propensity score software:  http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~estuart/propensityscoresoftware.html.

Personally, I like the `twang` package in R if you do want to do propensity score matching.

Comment: thank you...this is very helpful.  I'll follow through with your suggestions.